# tkinter frame ignoring width & height

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to build a scrollable table in TK inter.  I have been trying to follow some examples, mostly I am managing, but it seems that the child objects are causing the container frame to resize.  I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong.

Basically I am drawing controls in a frame, contained in a canvas, which is scrollable with a scrollbar.  This is then contained inside another frame.  I would like the canvas + scrollbar to follow the parent frame shape / size.

```
from tkinter import *
# Table class
class Table:
    # Initialize a constructor
    def __init__(self, fmeHeaders, fmeScrollableData, Headings, Data):

        total_rows = len(table_data)
        total_columns = len(table_data[0])

        for j in range(total_columns):
           self.entry = Entry(fmeHeaders, width=15, bg='LightSteelBlue',fg='Black',font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
           self.entry.grid(row=1, column=j)
           self.entry.insert(END, Headings[j])
                    
        # An approach for creating the table
        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):
                self.entry = Entry(fmeScrollableData, width=15, fg='blue', font=('Arial', 16, ''))

                self.entry.grid(row=i, column=j)
                self.entry.insert(END, Data[i][j])


table_header = ['ID', 'Name', 'City', 'Age']

# take the data
table_data = [(1, 'Gorge', 'California', 30),
              (2, 'Maria', 'New York', 19),
              (3, 'Albert', 'Berlin', 22),
              (4, 'Harry', 'Chicago', 19),
              (5, 'Vanessa', 'Boston', 31),
              (6, 'Ali', 'Karachi', 32),
              (7, 'John', 'Amsterdam', 23),
              (8, 'Tom', 'Berlin', 15),
              (9, 'Jane', 'Cape Town', 44),
              (10, 'Hugo', 'Sidney', 17),
              (11, 'Peter', 'Perth', 42),
              (12, 'Philip', 'Toronto', 77)]

# create root window
root = Tk()

fmeTable = Frame(root, relief='sunken',borderwidth=2, height=2000, width=200)

canvas = Canvas(fmeTable)
scroll_y = Scrollbar(fmeTable, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
fmeHeaders = Frame(fmeTable)
fmeHeaders.pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW)
fmeScrollableData = Frame(canvas)
table = Table(fmeHeaders, fmeScrollableData, table_header, table_data)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor='nw', window=fmeScrollableData)

### make sure everything is displayed before configuring the scrollregion
canvas.update_idletasks()

canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'), 
                 yscrollcommand=scroll_y.set)
                 
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side='left')
scroll_y.pack(fill='y', side='right')

fmeTable.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tend to solve these problems by implementing the stuff in pure Tcl/Tk with TkDocs website open for reference.

Comment: Change `fmeTable.pack()` to `fmeTable.pack(fill='both', expand=1)` if you want *"the canvas + scrollbar to follow the parent frame shape / size"*.

Comment: @acw1668 I don't want the frame to fill the parent.  I want the canvas and scrollbars to fill the frame fmeTable.   The child objects of fmeTable are forcing it to be a larger size than I want it to be.

Comment: Your code has already done that: `canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True, side='left')` and `scroll_y.pack(fill='y', side='right')`.

Comment: It seems that adding 
   `fmeTable.pack_propagate(False)
   fmeTable.pack()` right after defining fmeTable solved the problem.  I packed it at the end and tried pack_propagate there and it didn't work.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, that's right.  But I thought I needed that to make the canvas srollable.  What is the correct way to have a fixed viewing size for a scrolling canvas.  I guess telling it to expand, and then telling the parent not to expand a bit silly.

Comment: I think what you want is to specify the width and height of the canvas instead of `fmeTable`.

Comment: @acw1668 if I specify the height and width of the canvas it restricts the content and seems to be no longer scrollable.

Comment: As long as the height of `fmeScrollableData` is larger than the height of canvas, the scrolling should work.